# How exactly are parentheses (and other special symbols) rendered in LaTeX? How do they relate to the font used in the document?

Tags: sourcecode, rendering, integral, root

I am compiling this sample document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\(\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}\)
\(\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{x^2}\right)} \,dx\)
\(\left(\frac{2}{\frac{2}{\frac{2}{\frac{2}{\frac{2}{\frac{2}{\left(3\right)}}}}}}\right)\)
\end{document}
```

It draws tall parentheses that do *not* exactly match the glyph for the `(` character. Which is a good thing, because a taller symbol is indeed needed.

I am very curious to know where the code responsible for drawing those parentheses is. More specifically, I would like to know:

- Do those "custom" parentheses somehow match the `(` glyph of the font that's used for the rest of the LaTeX document?
- Similarly, how is the *shape* of the integral symbol decided? Is it somehow dependent on the font used for the LaTeX document? Is there a way to make an integral sign taller when its inner content grows? If so, how is the symbol drawn?
- How are square root drawn? Again, is the square root symbol somehow "linked" to the font of the other glyphs (letters, numbers)?

Comment: The parentheses in the example you cite come from the math font.  There are several different intrinsic sizes available in most math fonts (see the use of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg` to access them), plus there is also the means to make extensible symbols, by combining a top, bottom, and extensible middle of various symbols (`\left` and `\right` make use of these for very stretched versions).

Comment: there is no single "font" specifed for latex, for text there is the roman and separately italic, sans serif, typewriter etc.  math has up to 16 fonts specified, the math italic, the operator font (whenre small ( come from) a large operator font (big ( and big \sum etc) and up to a total of 16 other fonts for various symbols.

Comment: To answer your questions thoroughly would take close to an entire book. Fortunately, this book already exists; it's the "The TeXbook", written by Donald E. Knuth himself. You should focus, in particular, on chapters 16 to 19 as well as on Appendix G, "Generating Boxes from Formulas". You wrote, "I am very curious to know where the code responsible for drawing those parentheses is." The TeXbook will tell you.